# How do I correctly download a CSV with my own data?

Tags: jquery, string, csv, download

I have a little plugin I'm writing, which basically pulls information from the facebook API, loops over, creates a formatted string from the data that I want, and the forces a download once it's run, however, to my knowledge, I'm formatting the string correctly, but I can't open the csv (unless I'm being stupid, most likely the case...).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/vUnF9/848/

However, here's a very simple example, how I'm formatting my response I'm formatting my response:

```
var string = "a","b","c","d","e","f","etc";
```

To my knowledge, that is how the csv file expects it, yet it won't even work when I force that information into my `window.open` command near the top of the fiddle rather than pass it my custom string.

I know it's quite a big chunk of code, but I'm not sure what else I can do here?

Even if I run :`window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape("a","b","c","d","e","f","etc"))` directly, the csv downloads properly and opens, but there's no data..

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have couple of issues:

1) you are downloading too early. FB api call is ajax (aynch) call so you need to download only after it is success

2) You check `response.length`, response is an object and it does not have length property.

3) Using window.open to download csv, instead you can try using HTML5 anchor `download` attribute.

You can do something on these lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    FB.api(ids[i], 'get', function (response) {
        if (response) {
            //csvString = toCsv(response);   
            csvString += (hasRun == false ? getArrayValue(response, true) : getArrayValue(response, false));
            console.log(csvString);
            hasRun == true;

        }

        $('#keys').html(csvString);
           var tmpAnc=document.createElement('a');
           tmpAnc.textContent='download';
           tmpAnc.download="myFileName.csv";
           tmpAnc.href='data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(csvString);
           tmpAnc.click();

    });
    //updateprogressBar(i + 1, ids.length);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvyE/)**

*Also it seems like you are missing newlines after each row, everything gets displayed in single row*

And here it is for the other example:

```
$("#download").click(function() {
    var tempAnc    = document.createElement('a');
    tempAnc.href    = 'data:attachment/csv,' + escape($("#csv").val());
    tempAnc.target   = '_blank';
    tempAnc.download   = 'myFile.csv';
    tempAnc.click();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhcsQ/)**

**[Fiddle- Combined request](http://jsfiddle.net/wbW7C/)**

Comment: Ah, of course, thankyou so much, the new lines should be pretty easy :) thankyou again!

Comment: Do you mind me asking what the difference is between the `window.open` command, and the way you're creating an anchor?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins This is the first time even i did a real file download from client side. Somehow window.open doesn't work. So tried this option creating a temp anchor tag, but it worked still just have a check in different browsers once.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins let me play arnd with window.open, it seems like it is not downloading the file after changing something but there is no file name...

Comment: Okay, the problem I'm having now, is that because I need to call the 'FB' api multiple times, to keep adding to the variable `csvString`, it tries to download the file over and over, rather than making the string, then downloading it, can you think of a trick to allow this to work? http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/vjvyE/1/

Comment: @ShannonHochkins yes sure we can chain them to promise and use a then in the end for all call back hopefully if FbApi returns a promise.

Comment: That would be great! @PSL!

Comment: @ShannonHochkins do you have any client access token for fbapi? You can make a batch request but i get a response which says it needs access token.

Comment: All I have is the id's for the pages unfortunately :(

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Try this way as a fix. http://jsfiddle.net/dw8TF/ But there is a way to access it with access token with just one request, here is that fiddle which gives error as of now http://jsfiddle.net/JVCA9/. You can explore more on [batch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/#simple)

Comment: That's a neat little trick, I didn't even think about that! What error are you talking about though? I don't see any errors?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Run the second fiddle and see the console.log, there will be error response there. It says `message: "Top level access token or app id not specified for batch request."
type: "GraphBatchException"` .

Comment: Ah didn't even notice the second fiddle, oh well, it would be better to batch process rather than continuous get requests, however your first solution works fine! Thankyou again!

Comment: @ShannonHochkins You are welcome. Second fiddle in my comment only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using accents please consider prepend \ufeff

I use the text above with small changes. This is because without this you did UTF-8 without BOM, with you add this will work for pt-br and others languages that use accents.

tmpAnc.href='data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\ufeff'+escape(csvString);